# How to solve this series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to solve an exercise about quantum period finding.

Suppose $f(x+r) = f(x)$ with $0 \le x < N$ for $N$ an integer multiple of $r$. The exercise tells me to use this equivalence:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k \in \{0, r, 2r, \dots, N-r\}} e^{2 \pi i k \ell / N} = \left\{ \begin{matrix} \sqrt{N / r} \quad & \text{if } \ell \text{ is an integer multiple of } N / r \\ 0 \quad & \text{otherwise} \end{matrix}\right.
\end{aligned}
$$

This is clearly a geometric series. I tried to prove it because I'm not entirely sure about the square root in the result, but I miserably failed (I obtained a completely different result which I'm sure it's wrong).

Can you show this equivalence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k \in \{0, r, 2r, \dots, N-r\}} e^{2 \pi i k \ell / N} =
\sum_{j = 0 \cdots \frac{N}{r} -1 } e^{2 \pi i j \ell \,  r/ N}
\end{aligned}$.

Now if $l$  is an integer multiple of $N / r$, write $l = q N / r$, with $q$ integer, and we obtain 
$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j = 0 \cdots \frac{N}{r} -1 } e^{2 \pi i j q} = \sum_{j = 0 \cdots \frac{N}{r} -1 } 1 = \frac{N}{r}
\end{aligned}$
So indeed there should not be a square root.

Conversely, if $l$  is *not* an integer multiple of $N / r$, we use the geometric series:
$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j = 0 \cdots \frac{N}{r} -1 } e^{2 \pi i j \ell \,  r/ N} = \sum_{j = 0 \cdots \frac{N}{r} -1 } (e^{2 \pi i  \ell \,  r/ N})^j = \frac{1 - e^{2 \pi i  \ell} }{1  - e^{2 \pi i  \ell \,  r/ N}}
\end{aligned}$.

Also this is not zero in general, but only in the case that $l$ is an integer.